# Voltage regulatory

Tags: voltage, regulatory

I want to power & use a 12V DC amplified car woofer speaker,  i first tried powering it with a 12V DC - 1A adapter & it powered but when I plugged music in the input there was no sound at all, i now want to try & use a 16V DC adapter with 350mA  to power the same woofer & see if any sound will play; my question is can the 16V DC adapter work on the amplified car woofer without blowing it up?

Comment: Powering a car audio amplifier requires quite a lot of current, certainly more than 1 A at a reasonable volume. Your 12 V supply probably overloaded instantly when the music began playing, and shut down to protect itself. The 16 V 350 mA one is even *less* appropriate.

Comment: Do you have an amplifier? How are you connecting the music input to it?

Answer (score 2):

THINK POWER.

If it is rated at say 60 Watts then it will need 5 Amps from the 12 volt supply.

And I'm just assuming DC conditions here. Once we start into all the losses if the thing has its own power supply and then we start talking RMS and peak voltages and currents then we have more to worry about.

It could of course be much bigger than that. I suggest reading the label on the box.

Answer (score 0):

If the amplifier is designed to be used in a car, it should work correctly with a 12 - 14 volt power source - 16 volts *may* damage it (unlikely, but possible).  If the amp requires more than the 1 Amp that your 12 volt power source provided, then the 350 mA from the 16 volt supply is unlikely to be enough for it to work.

You need to determine the actual current required to operate the amplifier - it will almost certainly require more current when making a loud noise than when silent or at low volume.